# Memory management error with Mono?

Tags: memory-management, mono, nullreferenceexception

I have a program that was developed with C#/.NET 4.5.2 and runs fine on Windows (7 x64). The program handles a large amount of data, so it is compiled for x64 only. My largest input dataset can be processed on a PC with 16GB RAM.

When I try to run it on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit; 64 GB RAM installed, everything is fine for smaller datasets but I started getting SIGSEGV signals with larger datasets. These errors do not always occur at the same position, and for intermediate sized datasets, they sometimes don't occur at all.

I upgraded my version of Mono so I am now running with 5.0.1.1:

TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)

Upgrading replaced the error with a NullReferenceException:

Native stacktrace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Array:FastCopy (System.Array,int,System.Array,int,int)
  at System.Array.Copy (System.Array sourceArray, System.Int32 sourceIndex, System.Array destinationArray, System.Int32 destinationIndex, System.Int32 length) [0x00068] in <a07d6bf484a54da2861691df910339b1>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T].SetCapacity (System.Int32 newSize, System.Boolean forceNewHashCodes) [0x0000f] in <26aedeede9534b948c539f8734c8492d>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T].IncreaseCapacity () [0x00025] in <26aedeede9534b948c539f8734c8492d>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T].AddIfNotPresent (T value) [0x000bc] in <26aedeede9534b948c539f8734c8492d>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T].Add (T item) [0x00000] in <26aedeede9534b948c539f8734c8492d>:0 
  at MyLib.MyClass.DoProcessing () [0x00a6e] in <66a585adc1684679bfec565c73eb94e4>:0 
  at MyLib.MyClass.SynchProcessing () [0x00000] in <66a585adc1684679bfec565c73eb94e4>:0 
  at MyApp.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00139] in <e80b0468d8e642129fa7c39d5b2bb0a0>:0
```

In addition to HashSet< long >, it sometimes appears in Dictionary < long , Node > (where Node is a small class of two floats), but either way it is always when it is trying to add an element and in System.Array:FastCopy. This same location was reported by the older version of Mono when it gave a SIGSEGV. The errors occur in a single-threaded section of the code where the data is being read in & pre-processed (later it is multi-threaded, but that code has yet to produce the error, probably because all collections are already at their max size or shrinking)

So it looks like an internal pointer is being corrupted when a HashSet or Dictionary's underlying array is re-allocated.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  I think it looks like a memory manager / Garbage Collector error, or even an underlying bug in Mono? However, searching Google and this site has not turned anything up. I see that Mono has a new GC but mono -V says it is running be default (and the SIGSEGV was being produced when the older version was being used).

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions to try?

I don't know the heap & collection sizes when this error occurs. Next up I'll add some diagnostics to try and help although they'll make it slow and only give approximate values (eg. Console.WriteLine every 10,000 nodes, say)

Comment: Can confirm I see the same on mono 5.4.0.167 - other than that, same `--version` output. With a `HashSet<Type>` in my case and the NRE seems to occur in `AddIfNotPresent` but I don't think the set would be very large at all. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: My medium term solution is probably to port to .NET Core - that could well be next summer though. Currently running the largest datasets on the Windows PC and the others on the Ubuntu box. Would prefer the latter for all as it is then controlled by one big script, and I use the Windows PC for dev/etc!